# Tried finding the count of each letter in a word and storing the count in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The question was asked like this "Count the number of times each letter is repeating in the word MISSISSIPPI and store the count of each letter in a dictionary" and I used dict.get() method to get the count of each letter. I iterated the word with for loop and then I got stuck here

```
user_text='MISSISSIPPI'
dict={}
for keys in user_text:
    dict[keys]=dict.get(keys,0)+1
print("Count of all characters in MISSISSIPPI is : \n" +str(dict))
```

I am stuck in the line

```
dict[keys]=dict.get(keys,0)+1
```

I am not understanding how this line counts each letter

Comment: why not `collections.Counter(user_text)` ?

Comment: `from collections import Counter; Counter(user_text)`?

Comment: Are you asking for someone to explain your code to you?

Comment: or use defaultdict(int)

Answer (score 2):

the get() method would check if the key exists in the dict or not. If it does, it returns the value stored. If it doesn't exist, it would return the second argument as the default value.

In this case, the default is 0 (character never occurred before).

Then, it adds 1 to either and stores it in the dict

Comment: Finally, I prefer your answer than mine :-)

Answer (score 0):

dict[keys] is for getting the value of specific key or creating a key with it's value. if "keys" value doesn't exist in dict dictionary, python will add "keys" key with specific value to the list but will update it if "keys" key exists in the list.

for example:

```
a = {}
a["hello"] = "there"
print(a)
a["hello"] = "good morning"
print(a)
```

and the result is:

```
{"hello": "there"}
{"hello": "good morning"}
```

dict.get(keys) is also for getting the value of specific key. the zero that added after keys(.get(keys, 0)) is optional. A value to return if the specified key does not exist. Default value is None

So for example, loop sees the words "I". Python adds "I" key with value 1 (added with .get(keys, 0)+1) to the dictionary, and the next time that loop sees the word "I", because it was added in past, dict[keys] won't add "I" key to the list and will edit "I"'s value instead; that adds 1 to the value of "I" that will be 2 and will update it. (1 ====> 2).

i just edited the code that will print steps:

```
user_text='MISSISSIPPI'
dict={}
for keys in user_text:
    print(f"dict.get(keys, 0) = {dict.get(keys, 0)}")
    dict[keys]=dict.get(keys,0)+1
    print(f"keys = {keys}, dict[keys] = {dict[keys]}, dict = {dict}")
    print("------------------------------------------------")
print("Count of all characters in MISSISSIPPI is : \n" +str(dict))
```

and here's the results:

```
dict.get(keys, 0) = 0
keys = M, dict[keys] = 1, dict = {'M': 1}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 0
keys = I, dict[keys] = 1, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 1}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 0
keys = S, dict[keys] = 1, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 1, 'S': 1}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 1
keys = S, dict[keys] = 2, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 1, 'S': 2}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 1
keys = I, dict[keys] = 2, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 2, 'S': 2}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 2
keys = S, dict[keys] = 3, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 2, 'S': 3}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 3
keys = S, dict[keys] = 4, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 2, 'S': 4}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 2
keys = I, dict[keys] = 3, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 3, 'S': 4}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 0
keys = P, dict[keys] = 1, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 3, 'S': 4, 'P': 1}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 1
keys = P, dict[keys] = 2, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 3, 'S': 4, 'P': 2}
------------------------------------------------
dict.get(keys, 0) = 3
keys = I, dict[keys] = 4, dict = {'M': 1, 'I': 4, 'S': 4, 'P': 2}
------------------------------------------------
Count of all characters in MISSISSIPPI is : 
{'M': 1, 'I': 4, 'S': 4, 'P': 2}
```

this's a nice developed code, 10/10.

wish you find it helpful.

[Python Dictionary .get() explanations in w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)